# sendmail Ошибка сертификата

Tags: ubuntu, bash, sendmail, postfix, сертификат

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите как решить проблему с ошибкой сертификата.

```
sendEmail -f mail@mail.ru -t mail1@mail.ru -o tls=yes -u "!" -m "!" -s 12.18.12.10:587 -xu mail@mail.ru -xp passwd
```

почта не уходит выдаёт:

```
May 25 13:34:54 it3 sendEmail[17883]: ERROR => TLS setup failed: SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

вывод команды ls -l /etc/ssl/certs/*root_CA*

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1172 май 19 10:04 /etc/ssl/certs/root_CA.pem
```

ls /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla | grep root_CA

```
root_CA.crt
```

как сопоставить или установить сертификат не догоняю, куда копать и что делать подскажите.

Comment: Покажите вывод команды `cat /usr/bin/sendemail | grep -n "$SERVER, SSL_version =>"`

Comment: Заголовок не соответствует вопросу (`sendmail` != `sendEmail`).

Comment: 1933:            if (! IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL($SERVER, SSL_version => 'SSLv23:!SSLv2')) {

Comment: У вас установлен `sendemail` и `sendEmail`?

Comment: sendemail установлен а sendEmail "E: Не удалось найти пакет sendEmail"

Comment: Попробуйте установить `sendEmail`.

Comment: E: Не удалось найти пакет sendEmail